# How can I read/ write to a single array in json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a simple script that can store data in a json file. Every time you save the form it creates a new array. I just want to update goal and raised in the same array.

form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
Goal:<br>
<input type="text" name="goal">
<br><br/>
Raised:<br>
<input type="text" name="raised">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php

$myFile = "data.json";
$arr_data = array();

try
{      
    $formdata = array(
        'goal'=> $_POST['goal'],
        'raised'=> $_POST['raised']
    );

    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
            echo 'Data successfully saved';
        }
    else 
            echo "error";

}
catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_push` appends. You want to replace existing, not add, right? So:

```
<?php

$myFile = "data.json";

try {      
    $arr_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($myFile), true);

    // don't forget to validate first of course:
    $arr_data['goal'] = $_POST['goal'];
    $arr_data['raised'] = $_POST['raised'];

    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

...
```

Comment: Exactly, I want to replace the existing array.

Answer (score 2):

```php
<?php

$formdata = array(
    'goal'=> $_POST['goal'],
    'raised'=> $_POST['raised']
);


try {

    $fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($formdata));
    fclose($fp);

}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    // Caught Some Exception
}
```

You can simply use `fopen()` and `fwrite()` to open and write to a file. The data will be replaced with new data.

Answer (score 0):

To Archive, this file_put_contents won't help much.

Whenever someone posts data from a form, you have to open your file(data.json) in append mode(a). then write your content using `fwrite` or `fopen`.

In this case, you will get all single data set as a separate array. Not a single array

Comment: Aah I see, so the file_put_contents is the one that creates a new array each time?

Comment: file_put_contents  will just Write data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);`, `$arr_data` becomes an associative array, this means you can simply do `$arr_data['goal'] = $_POST['goal']` or `$arr_data['goal'] = $formdata['goal']`, after which you can re-encode the array and save it to your file. So you only need to switch the line with the `array_push()` call, to the code I've just explained. This works for both `'goal'` and `'raised'` keys

Comment: It's worth to mention that you may want to sanitize your data before doing this. **Don't put this code in production!!! as you might be exposing yourself to attacks**

Comment: True! This is just a start. Eventually the form will be behind a login system as well. And with sanitizing you mean don't let users input something like `<script>alert('Hello')</script>` in the form right?